# Android App not displyed on play store for Nexus 5X (Android 6.0.1)

Tags: android, google-play, android-version

My app not visible in play store for "**Nexus 5X (Android 6.0.1)**" but visible to other devices. Why it is so?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Manifest file**

Below these are permissions and compatible screen support and SDK target

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <!-- Map related permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ef.myef.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--  -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <!-- for xxhdpi -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
       <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />


    </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

Comment: Is showing on devices having  version 6.0.1 ?

Comment: Yes your right...Its 6.0.1  do I have to update to target version to 23..

Comment: complete manifest? do you use any weird/unusual uses-feature or uses-permission? also try maxSdkVersion=23

Comment: @eriuzo I edited  my question and manifest file...Let me check maxSdkVersion= 23 you mentioned...Plz let me know thing wrong manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Nexus 5x is on 420 dpi by default.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.id/2015/09/android-marshmallow-ready-for-devices.html

> Nexus 5X has a quantized density of 420 dpi, which falls in between the xhdpi and xxhdpi primary density buckets

therefore you should add to your manifest

```
<screen
    android:screenDensity="420"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
```

Comment: Thanks,Looks like that is the issue,Let me check and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

> uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" /

Android 6.0.1 is 23, not 22. Try

uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" /

Comment: Check black list of supported devices for your google play console project. May be it blocked.